# How to set Cuttlefish.io base URL used in sent mails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, transactional-email

I am using Cuttlefish.io (http://www.cuttlefish.io), and I would like to know how to set the base URL used in links and counter image. By default, the links base URL is:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

But I would like to set it to a proper base URL, different to this default base URL.

How to do that?

Comment: have you tried to update your asset_host in environment config ? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do, by adding this to environments' .rb files:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "#{config.cuttlefish_domain}" }
```

And then put the value I want in environment thru:

```
export CUTTLEFISH_DOMAIN=mydomain
```